# Proto files missing input error while compiling proto files

Tags: python-3.x, protocol-buffers

My proto directory have following files .

```
(virtualenv) home/Application/proto# account.proto  asset.proto  float_account.proto  __init__.py  organization_account.proto  payload.proto  __pycache__  share_asset.proto
```

The Application directory has two folders.

```
(virtualenv) home/Application# protocompiled proto
```

I am getting this error "Missing input file .) when from the parent directory, I run this command to compile proto files

```
(virtualenv) home/Application# python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I .proto/payload.proto  --python_out=protocompiled
```

I am getting the same error if i change directory to proto directory and run the following command i.e Missing input file.

```
(virtualenv) home/Application/proto# python -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=payload.proto
```

Versions:

```
protobuf==3.6.1
grpcio==1.14.2
grpcio-tools==1.14.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cd to the parent directory of the proto. You need to provide filename at the end.

```
(virtualenv) home/Application# python -m grpc_tools.protoc --python_out=protocompiled --proto_path=proto payload.proto
```